# ffmpeg avcodec_find_encoder_by_name failes to find encoder h264_nvenc

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, decode, nvidia

When I run this command "ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc" in the terminal it gives me the following output
[image]

and I am able to use the encoder through the command line interface but it got a problem when I try to run from the following source code.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <x264.h>
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;

    av_register_all();

    std::cout << "Loading codec" << std::endl;

//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name( "libx264" ); // works
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name( "h264_nvenc" );
   // codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name( "h264_cuvid" );
    if( !codec )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Unable to find codec!" );
    }

    std::cout << "Allocating context" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works on my system (finds encoder). Make sure your ffmpeg source is up to date and configured and compiled with `--enable-nvenc`.

**Update:**
Can you please save above snipped as h264_nvenc.cpp and compile with this command:

```
g++ h264_nvenc.cpp -o h264_nvenc `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --cflags libavformat libswscale libswresample libavutil libavcodec` `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config --libs libavformat libswscale libswresample libavutil libavcodec` -std=gnu++11
```

And than test the compiled file as `./h264_nvenc`

You should then see:

```
Loading codec
Allocating context
```

Comment: Thanks kamilz for your reply, I did compiled it with --enable-nvenc as you can see it from the picture  and I can get  a list of supported profiles with the following commands:  ffmpeg -h encoder=nvenc_h264 , ffmpeg -h encoder=nvenc_hevc . the problem is when I try to use them in the code.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the picture (for some reasoun stack.imgur.com is blocked) anyway I see it now. And can I see your Makefile ?

Comment: I couldn't paste the Make file here,but Please look at this link for the Makefile both for the above code and for ffmpeg .    https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_VI3gAcFpqIfMU1o-Fko9zsidZwsXSFp?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer, please check. PS.: you should fix the paths.

Comment: @Kamilz Thank you so much. I have been missing -lswscale and -lswresample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear CMakeLists.txt file for this minimal example. Note that the libraries are not linked correctly if one uses `link_directories( /usr/local/lib )`, so I used `add_library` instead.

Furthermore, it seems not to be necessary to include the nvidia/cuda libraries to have access to nvenc codecs.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( opencv-test )

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable( h264_nvenc
  h264_nvenc.cpp 
)

# link_directories( /usr/local/lib ) # does not work

add_library( avformat SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( avformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so )

add_library( avutil SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( avutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so )

add_library( avcodec SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( avcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so )

add_library( swscale SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( swscale PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libswscale.so )

add_library( swresample SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( swresample PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libswresample.so )

target_link_libraries( h264_nvenc avformat swscale swresample avutil avcodec)
```